# why is the gradle syntax of my projects different from that of everyone else's?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

in my kotlin android projects the gradle syntax must look like this way, and doesn't support many of the features/lines posted around in tutorials and other answers here, why?

in my projects, the dependency implementation line must look like this

```
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
```

but everywhere else what i see is this, and this is not at all supported in my project

```
    implementation'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1'
```

lines and functions like below don't work at all and i have no idea how to configure the gradle to read them or make them work.

```
    api project(':module-name')
```

```
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

on such lines i get all kinds of syntax errors, unresolved references, unexpected tokens and so on

my project's gradle looks like this

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation (":RFIDAPI3Library")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

i don't understand what's going on and where the difference lays

Comment: When you are creating projects (assuming you use Android Studio), you choose the build system (I believe you chose Gradle). Under that option there is an option to choose the language. By default it is Kotlin but you can choose Groovy. This will make your gradle files like others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered these problems too. Gradle scripts are written in either Groovy DSL or Kotlin DSL (domain-specific language).

What you have in your studio is Kotlin DSL and other code are of Groovy DSL. There is no duffrence in functionality, it's just the syntax.

You can always find the correct syntax on the official documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html).
By clicking that link you can modify your gradle accordinly.